Opening a website on school's computers as prank
I'm looking for a movie which features a scene where in a high-school or college, a boy pranks a girl by opening a website with naked men photos on the school's computer. Could you help me finding its name?
The scenes I remember are as follows:
They're in school or some other kind of educational facility, and subject of the lesson uses computers. The girl goes away for some seconds, and the guy sets-up her computer to open the mentioned website. I remember that then the teacher sees this and gets angry with her.
As for the identifiable information:
The release date is between 2000-2010, I don't recall the exact date.

If you recognize any cast it should narrow it down.

Can you narrow down the timeline?

The movie is It's a Boy Girl thing (2006). This movie is a romantic comedy movie set in a high school. The male lead and female lead are former childhood friends but are totally different in their characters. He is a silly guy interested in football whereas she is a bookish girl interested in literature.
The plot goes like this.

Woody Deane (Kevin Zegers) and Nell Bedworth (Samaire Armstrong) are neighbors and former childhood friends who go to the same high school, but are otherwise completely different. Woody is a popular varsity football player while Nell is a girl who loves literature but lacks social skills. They loathe each other and are constantly in dispute. One day their class goes on a school trip to a museum and they are forced to work together on an assignment. 

The scene you are describing comes just before they go to the field trip in the museum. The professor in the class going on was Early History. All the students open the page in their computers as instructed by her. Nell Bedworth (Samaire Armstrong) bends down to grab a book to note down a reference. Meanwhile, Woody Deane (Kevin Zegers) opens a porn website to prank her(She had a bad discussion with him just before this scene. So, he does like that). All the students in the room give an awkward look to her and the lecturer gets angry on her. 
